# How to conditionally-dispatch / "cascade" actions in Redux

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on a vanilla-js app (self-contained UI component) and I've been trying to use Redux to make some of the logic easier to test and reason about.

There is a UI event / user-action (let's call it "DO_SOMETHING_ACTION") which can be triggered a couple of different ways in the UI:

1. Through key-presses
2. By dragging with the mouse

For #1 it's simple enough - I'm happy to have the UI component determine whether the appropriate keys were pressed in the event handler and dispatch the Redux "DO_SOMETHING_ACTION" directly.

For #2 the business rules as to whether we should dispatch "DO_SOMETHING_ACTION" or "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE" (or perhaps nothing at all) **are quite complex**. I want to be able to *reason about* and *test* this logic - hence my thinking was to dispatch a "MAYBE_DO_SOMETHING" action (with the minimum necessary information from the event handler captured *and abstracted*).

Can I/should I solve this problem by making the dispatch of "MAYBE_DO_SOMETHING" a thunk? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Apologies if the question title is misleading - please feel free to change it to something more appropriate!

Comment: How about making a function called `shouldIDoSomething(theCurrentState)` that returns a boolean. Then use that function to determine if an action should be dispatched. Then write unit tests against that function.

Comment: @sissonb It would need to return an action (either "DO_SOMETHING", "DO_SOMETHING_ELSE" or null) since I'll want to test the action is correctly populated too. But yeah, seems like that's the "simplest thing that could possibly work" - thanks

Comment: You could make two functions. One for DO_SOMETHING, and one for DO_SOMETHING_ELSE. `shouldIDoSomething(theCurrentState)` `shouldIDoSomethinglse(theCurrentState)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly *possible* to implement this with a thunk:

```
export const dragOverAction = function(payload: DragOverActionPayload) {
  return function(dispatch: Dispatch, getState: () => GlobalStateTree) {
      // Various business logic
      if (someCondition) {
        return;
      }

      if (anotherCondition) {
        dispatch(doSomething({
          <snip>
        }));
      } else if (anotherCondition) {
        dispatch(doSomethingElse({
          <snip>       
        }));
      }

      // Otherwise, don't dispatch anything.
  }
}
```

Testing is not as bad as I'd anticipated:

```
import configureMockStore from "redux-mock-store";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export const mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk]); 
import * as allActions from "../app/actions/index";

describe("dragOverAction", function() {
    it("should <blah blah>", async function() {
        let store = mockStore();
        await store.dispatch<any>(allActions.dragOverAction({
            foo: bar,
            <snip>
        }));
        const actions = store.getActions();

        expect(actions).toBe(<snip>);
    });
});
```